# Proving a function is stable if and only if $|f'(x)| \geq c$.

Tags: calculus, limits

> A function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *stable*
>   provided that
>
> $$|f(x) - f(y)| \geq c|x - y|$$ for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$,
>   where $c > 0$ is called the *stability constant*.

Prove a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is stable if and only if it satisfies

$$|f'(x)| \geq c$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

My attempt:

First assume $f$ is stable so we have $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq c|x - y$|. Dividing each side by $|x - y|$ we get

$$\frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x - y|} \geq c.$$

Finally, take the limit as $y$ approaches $x$ to get $f'(x) \geq c$.

Now we do the other direction. Suppose $|f'(x)| \geq c$ holds. By the definition of a limit,

$$\lim_{x_0 \to x} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} \geq c$$

$$\lim_{x_0 \to x} |f(x) - f(x_0)| \geq \lim_{x_0 \to x} c|x-x_0| $$

---

My questions:

1) Is what I've done so far correct?

2) How can I justify taking the limit away? I'll be done if the limits aren't there in the backwards direction.

Thanks

Comment: So far it is correct, maybe you can say what regularity you give to $f$ (I guess it's just differentiable). For "the other direction" you might want to use the Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: Are we assuming that $f$ is differentiable, or is that something we want to show?

Comment: Sorry, $f$ is differentiable. We know it.